# Not getting all records or filtered records

Tags: c#, .net, redmine, redmine-api

I am getting data from `redmine timeentry`.

The issue is i am getting only last 25 records.
My filters are not working

Any idea, why filters are not working or what type of mistake I am doing?

I have installed package of `redmine` from `Nuget`

Here is the code:

```
string host = "redmine.xyz.net";
string apiKey = "e69e2243f4b357f34533322408d6339b7f5b2579e36";

var manager = new RedmineManager(host, apiKey);
List<EEmployeeTimeSheet> liEmpTimeSheet = new List<EEmployeeTimeSheet>();
var parameters = new NameValueCollection();
parameters.Add("per_page", "100");
parameters.Add("created_on", DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
settings.CloseOutput = false;
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/test.xml")), settings);
var timeentry=manager.GetObjectList<TimeEntry>(parameters).Take(100);
foreach (var issue in timeentry)
{
     issue.WriteXml(xmlWriter);
     EEmployeeTimeSheet emp = new EEmployeeTimeSheet();
     emp.strActivity = issue.Activity.ToString();
     emp.strComments = issue.Comments;
     emp.nHours = issue.Hours;
     emp.dtCreatedOn = issue.CreatedOn;
     emp.strProject = issue.Project.Name;
     emp.strEmployeeName = issue.User.Name;
     liEmpTimeSheet.Add(emp);
}
xmlWriter.Flush();
xmlWriter.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the API returns 25 items only.
You may use an overload of the GetObjects() method:

```
const int limit = 1000;
var parameters = new string[0];
IList<Project> redmineProjects = 
   manager.GetObjects<Project>(limit: limit, offset: 0, include: parameters);
```